# Is it possible to validate a Webhook Event is registered / Trigger an event?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I integrated Stripe into our application. Now I need to make sure, our customers configured it correctly, so I can show a warning instead of the checkout form.

My first thought was, when a `payment_intent.created` comes to my webhook, I update some state in my database, that the webhook was receiving it, and before checkout, I will validate against this.

However, the customer can select specific events, which will be signaled to the webhook. If he doesn't have `payment_intent.succeeded` enabled, it will never been fired. And that's what I need to validate most specificaly.

So:

1. Is there a way, to validate, if the `payment_intent.succeeded` is redirected to the webhook (of course before a customer gets charged)?
2. Alternative: Is there a way to trigger an Event via API?

I know, I can trigger an Event via the CLI:

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

But this doesn't help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/cli) approach would work *if* your CLI instance was signed in to your customer's Stripe account or you could use their [API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/api_keys).  This would allow you to specify the live API key as well.

If you have the customer's API keys, you can use the [Webhooks API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints).  You can retrieve the webhooks for the customer's account and examine what events they are configured for.  You can even [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/update) the webhook to listen for the `payment_intent.succeeded` event if it is not currently being listened to.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, specifcaly [how to create it dynamicaly](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create). Not sure how I have missed this. Thx